# How to do -8 x -8 in a 4 bit booth multiplier?

Tags: algorithms, computer-architecture, arithmetic, multiplication

In the general case of an n bit booth multiplier, the maximum negative value is -2<sup>n-1</sup>. So with 4 bits we can represent -8 x -8 (M=1000, Q=1000). Now if we follow Booth's algorithm for multiplying n-bit numbers:

| count | A | Q | Q<sub>-1</sub> | Operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 0000 | 1000 | 0 | Initial Conditions |
| 3 | 0000 | 0100 | 0 | (00) Shift and decrement count |
| 2 | 0000 | 0010 | 0 | (00) Shift and decrement count |
| 1 | 0000 | 0001 | 0 | (00) Shift and decrement count |
| 1 | 1000 | 0001 | 0 | (10) A <= A-M |
| 0 | 1100 | 0000 | 1 | Shift and decrement count |

The result is 11000000<sub>2</sub> = -64<sub>10</sub> which is clearly not correct. Am I missing something? Is this just a limitation of Booth's algorithm? I have a hard time believing this isn't a known issue, but I can't seem to find any source that even mentions it.

I can see the issue is when we need to do A<=A-M, since the result should be +8 in this case which can't be expressed in 4-bit 2's complement. How would this be addressed in an actual hardware implementation of Booth's algorithm?

Comment: (See *The above-mentioned technique is inadequate…* in [en.wikipedia's Example](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm#Example).)

Comment: @greybeard Thanks! Guess I should have read the Wikipedia article more carefully.